# Multiple intents handling in chatbot

Tags: chatbot, rasa

I am developing a bot for banking purposes using RASA. I have intents for fund transfer, transaction history, loan, balance, bill payments, etc. I have implemented intents for handling the functionalities one at a time. And now, I want to handle multiple intents at a time.

For e.g, if a user says,

**Show my latest transactions and then pay my bill after showing the balance.**

How can I handle these kinds of inputs where the user asks for more than one or two functionalities in a single utterance?

I know, I can implement intents with multiple entities, but that seems to be not working for me as I have so many intents that I cannot afford to make intents with the combination of 2 or 3 entities.

Is it even possible to implement using RASA or any other technology for building a chatbot?

Comment: Refer [How to handle multiple intents](https://blog.rasa.com/how-to-handle-multiple-intents-per-input-using-rasa-nlu-tensorflow-pipeline/)

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar, I have read it. It only tells how can implement 2 entities. Doesn't go any further.

Answer (score 5):

### Approach 1 - multi-intents

You can use multi-intents (not to be confused with multi-entities). What you need to do is:

- Write example nlu data for the intent separately (what you already have)
- Write nlu data for the multi-intents combinations. In theory, Rasa will use both the information from both the single intent and multi-intent examples to correctly categorize. This means that you do not need that many training examples in the multi-intent
- Write some stories that deal with these multi-intents
- Specify a separator in the tokenizer configuration: `intent_split_symbol: "+"`

Please note that you need to have both NLU data for the multi-intents you want to support and stories, otherwise Rasa won't recognize them in the NLU and won't do anything in the Core.

References:

- [Rasa documentation for multi-intents](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/tuning-your-model/#doing-multi-intent-classification)
- [Blog post](https://blog.rasa.com/how-to-handle-multiple-intents-per-input-using-rasa-nlu-tensorflow-pipeline/) (be careful, the configuration changed since then, you should rather follow the documentation)

### Example

This could give you something like this:

**nlu.md**

```markdown
# intent:show transactions
- please show me my latest transactions
- show me my transactions
- ...

# intent:pay bill
- pay my bill please
- i want to pay my bill
- go ahead and pay the bills
- ...

# intent:show transactions+pay bill
- Show my latest transactions and then pay my bill after showing the balance.
- show me my transactions and go ahead and pay the bills
-
```

Note that you could write a script to automatically generate a few examples of multi-intents from the single intents

**stories.md**

```markdown
# story 1
* show transactions
- action_show_transactions

# story 2
* pay bill
- action_pay_bill

# story 3 (combined)
* show transactions+pay bill
- action_show_transactions
- action_pay_bill
```

**config.yml**

```
language: "en"

pipeline:
- name: "WhitespaceTokenizer"
  intent_split_symbol: "+"
- name: "CountVectorsFeaturizer"
- name: "EmbeddingIntentClassifier"
```

Please note that I'm using a different split symbol than the one in the documentation.

### Approach 2 - instructions as entities

Another approach is to use a single intent `ask_action` and one or more entities that identifies your instructions.

You can then have an action `action_execute_instructions` that deals with all of them. It would look at the entities from the latest message, and execute whatever you need.

How you understand the instructions will strongly depend on how you chose to define the entities and how you manage to map them to the instruction you want. There is the `SynonymMapper` for that but it is not flexible at all and will fail if you have a new example that does not exactly match. You're better off writing your own NLU pipeline component in that case.

To be honest, I don't think this is a good approach. Entities should rather be, well, entities (ie: objects, locations, etc.)

**nlu.md**

```markdown
# intent:ask_action
- [Show my latest transactions](instruction) and then [pay my bill](instruction) after showing the balance.
- [show me my transactions](instruction) and go ahead and [pay the bills](instruction)
- [pay the bill](instruction)
```

**stories.md**

```markdown
# story 1
* ask_action
- action_execute_instructions
```

### Recommendations

I would strongly recommend using the simplest approach. Once you have your bot live, you should review how your users use it and see if a more complex combination of intent (if you do multi-intents) is needed.

Comment: Thanks @nbeuchat, according to your approach I can combine the intents. But, what if I have 5 different intents and I have to make combinations of 3 and 4 intents together? It doesn't seem feasible.

Comment: That's unfortunately how it would work with multi-intent although I'm really not sure how good this would work when combining 3-4 intents in a single sentence. The question you need to ask yourself is how real users actually use your bot? Do you really have cases with 3-4 intents at once?

If you really want to support many instructions, you could try the entities approach where you'd have a single intent with each instruction being an entity. However, you'd need to be careful on the entity resolution as the SynonymMapper would not be enough. I can update my answer with such an approach

Comment: @VishalA. FYI, I have updated the answer with an alternative approach using entities (although I'd not recommend using this one tbh)

Comment: I don't think approach 2 will give decent accuracy at all. NER prediction is based on the entity value and the structure of the sentence around the occurrence of a certain type of entity. If you use "instruction" as an entity, you are basically asking the model to predict "all" the intents under one entity instruction. Secondly, you will have to build/use your own intent predictor in the custom action to make sense of what the instruction is (basically you made no use of intent predictor of rasa). Not recommended at all.

Comment: @nbeuchat the rasa docs for multiple intents have moved to https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/tuning-your-model/#doing-multi-intent-classification

Comment: Thank you @PhilC, I have updated the link in my answer